# Como agregar un signo a una cadena en determinada posición

Tags: javascript

Quiero poner un "-" antes del ultimo carácter de una cadena independientemente de su longitud y verificar si el ultimo carácter es un numero o una letra y si es una letra ponerla en mayúscula.

Comment: ¿Qué has intentado?

Comment: intente con el split pero ya vi que no me servira estoy buscando algo para buscar un caracter, capturar su posicion para hacerle un substring en la posicion del guion suena logico pero investigando.

Comment: ¿Puedes poner algún ejemplo? Y el código de lo que has intentado...

Comment: oDatos.rut = "56789-x"
var x = oDatos.rut.split(",");
asi solo me separo todo con comas , tambien hice algo como var txt = "2342-4"; var txt2 = txt.length-1 pero me dio resultado 5 vere que veo por ahi que pueda combinar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes hacerlo de la siguiente forma:

```js
var text = "Texto de prueba"
// Tomas el largo del string.
var length = text.length; 
// Aqui tomar el ultimo caracter y validas con regex si es una letra entre a-z, si es asi lo pasas a mayusculas.
var lastChar = /[a-z]/.test(text.slice(length-1)) ? text.slice(length-1).toUpperCase() : text.slice(length-1);
// lo partes y agregas el "-"
var output = [text.slice(0, length-1), "-", lastChar].join('');
console.log(output);
```

> Asumo que te llega en formato "`string`" por eso hablas de `cadena` y
>   `caracter`.

Comment: te pasaste :O guardare eso por ahio seguramente en el futuro lo necesitare

Answer (score 0):

Una forma con menos código podría ser

```
var foo = "A test strings";

var output = [foo.slice(0,foo.length - 1,), '-', foo.slice(-1).toUpperCase()].join('');
console.log(output)
```